# How do I get DirectorySecurity from unc path which contains '.' as localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, localhost

First of all I want to point out that all needed permessions for access has been got.

```
private static IEnumerable<FileSystemAccessRule> GetDirectoryAccessRules(string directoryPath)
{
     AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = Directory.GetAccessControl(directoryPath);
```

The problem is if `directoryPath` contains `'.'` as `'localhost'` the exception will be being thrown. (`InvalidOperationException`). Bit if `'.'` is changed on `'localhost'` all works fine.

[image]

Is there any pretty way to solve this situation except of course regular string modification ? Something like `Path.Combine` etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace the character dot(.) that come 1st time in directory path

```
 if (directoryPath.Contains('.') && directoryPath.IndexOf('.') != directoryPath.LastIndexOf('.')) 
 {
   var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("."));
   directoryPath = regex.Replace(directoryPath, ".", 1);
 }
```

Comment: Ok, I upvote your answer, but also advise to you read carefully the question! The question is 'Is there any pretty way to solve this situation except of course regular string modification ?'